# Order of arguments for C bitwise operations?

Tags: c, operator-precedence, bitwise-and

I've gotten a piece of software working, and am now trying to tune it up so it runs faster.  I discovered something that struck as well - just bizarre.  It's no longer relevant, because I switched to using a pointer instead of indexing an array (it's faster with the pointers), but I'd still like to know what is going on.

Here's the code:

```
short mask_num_vals(short mask)
{
        short count = 0;

        for(short val=0;val<NUM_VALS;val++)
                if(mask & val_masks[val])
                        count++;
        return count;
}
```

This small piece of code is called many many times.  What really surprised me is that this code runs significantly faster than its predecessor, which simply had the two arguments to the "&" operation reversed.

Now, I would have thought the two versions would be, for all practical purposes, identical, and they do produce the same result.  But the version above is faster - noticeably faster.  It makes about a 5% difference in the running time of the overall code that uses it.  My attempt to measure the amount of time spent in the function above failed completely - measuring the time used up far more time than actually executing the rest of the code.  (A version of Heisenberg's principle for software, I guess.)

So my picture here is, the compiled code evaluates the two arguments, and then does a bitwise "and" on them.  Who cares which order the arguments are in?  Apparently the compiler or the computer does.

My completely unsupported conjecture is that the compiled code must be evaluating "val_masks[val]" for *each bit*.  If "val_masks[val]" comes first, it evaluates it for every bit, if "mask" comes first, it doesn't bother with "val_masks[val]" if that particular bit in "mask" is zero.  I have no evidence whatsoever to support this conjecture; I just can't think of anything else that might cause this behaviour.

Does this seem likely?  This behaviour just seemed weird to me, and I think points to some difference in my picture of how the compiled code works, and how it actually works.  Again, not all that relevant any more, as I've evolved the code further (using pointers instead of arrays).  But I'd still be interested in knowing what is causing this.

Hardware is an Apple MacBook Pro 15-inch 2018, MacOS 10.15.5.  Software is gcc compiler, and "gcc --version" produces the following output.

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Compiled with the command "gcc -c -Wall 'C filename'", linked with "gcc -o -Wall 'object filenames'".

Comment: try to compile both versions of code using `gcc -O2` and see there's no difference in assembly.

Comment: Few questions: What are the compilation flags you used? What is the value of `NUM_VALS`? what are the masks in `val_masks[]` and how+where this array is defined?

Comment: You can compile with `gcc -S` to see the assembly.

Comment: Read more about [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). You want to use `gcc -Wall -O3 -S -fverbose-asm`. Actually, you use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) whose documentation you should read. Read also the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) explaining what optimizations are possible

Comment: "*I switched to using a pointer instead of indexing an array (it's faster with the pointers),*" -- that's not universally true. It more likely reflects the fact that you haven't set the optimization level when compiling your code -- or you have other issues. The compiler is fully capable of optimizing indexing just as it can when using pointers.

Comment: Is this _yet_ another "benchmarking non-optimized code" fiasco? It gets really old to answer those over and over. Compile with -O3. Turns out it doesn't make sense to discuss the optimizer while it is disabled. Kind of like asking helpdesk why your computer isn't working when you haven't turned the power on.

Comment: As for the order of evaluation of &, it is unspecified, so it won't matter which one that comes first. Unlike special case operators like &&.

Comment: Thanks for all comments.  For some reason, I thought the default level of optimisation was something moderate, not zero.  The difference between the two versions is much smaller, or perhaps zero, at the "-O1" level.

Still, even without optimisation, I'm surprised.  I thought the bitwise and would correspond to a processor command, which would essentially be symmetric in the two arguments.  Maybe it translates into a more extended algorithm.  I might have a look at the assembly code, as suggested, but I think this will require some improvement in my skill level - it's been a few decades :(

Comment: When I say thanks for all comments, I mean except for this one "Kind of like asking helpdesk why your computer isn't working when you haven't turned the power on."

Answer (score 1):

Code optimizers are often unpredictable. Their output can change after small meaningless tweaks in code, or after changing command-line options, or after upgrading the compiler. You cannot always explain why the compiler does some optimization in one case but not in another; you can guess all you want, but only experience can show.

One powerful technique in determining what is going on: convert your two versions of code to assembly language and compare.

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) could be [invoked](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) with the command-line switch `-S` for that.

```
gcc -S -Wall -O -fverbose-asm your-c-source.c
```

which produces a textual assembler file `your-c-source.s` (you could glance into it using a pager like `less` or a source code editor like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) from the C file `your-c-source.c`

The [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compiler has similar options.